# SQLite extremely slow on first SELECT statement

Tags: c#, performance, caching, sqlite

I've got a table with about 90 000 rows. On disk size (of this table) ~60 Mb.

To search I'm using pattern `LIKE '%xxx%'`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE '%value%' 
LIMIT 20
```

Columns are not indexed because SQLite doesn't use indexes when `LIKE` pattern starts with wildcard character.

It takes ~30 seconds to perform it at the first time. At the second time it takes 100 ms max. I know about cold and warm cache but I just could not believe that it takes so much time to read table in memory. Visual Studio profiler shows sloooooowly rising memory usage. Ok. Maybe searching is too slow? But not. Simple `SELECT * FROM table` shows us the same ~30 seconds to read 60 Mb.

I've tried to increase cache with `PRAGMA cache_size = -100000;`, to build sqlite dll with `SQLITE_THREADSAFE=0`. It doesn't helps.

I'm using `System.Data.Sqlite` in my C# application, but tested on simple `sqlite3.dll`. Same. Database is using an UTF-16le encoding.